# How to make sorting HTML tables faster?

Tags: javascript

I am a Javascript newbie. After trying out many Javascript and Jquery plugins to sort my HTML table and ending up disappointed, I decided to implement my own Javascript code for sorting HTML tables. The code I wrote is an update from W3Schools.

```
function sortFunctionNumeric(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("reportingTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (Number(x.innerHTML) > Number(y.innerHTML)) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (Number(x.innerHTML) < Number(y.innerHTML)) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now the sorting works perfectly fine. However, it is very slow!

I deal with a lot of rows of daqta(depending on project, it can go up to 9000 rows). 
Is there a way to speed up my Javascript code?

Comment: Remove the rows from the DOM, sort them, re-add them to the DOM -> [`document.createDocumentFragement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

Comment: Actually just hide the rows gives a very god effekt.
Render is usually the heavy thing in this.

Comment: It's slow because you're using a bad sorting algorithm (after a quick-glance it looks like bubble-sort with polynomial time `O(n^2)` because it iterates through the table for each row (the `for` inside the `while`). Use JavaScript's built-in sorting algorithm at `Array.prototype.sort` instead.

Comment: How is your `sortFunctionNumeric` meant to be invoked? Is `n` meant to be the column index? (I note that your function will fail if there is a `colspan` or `rowspan` in the table).

Comment: @Dai Yes. The `n` is the column index.

Comment: Another possible optimization would be, instead of using `getElementsByTagName()` multiple times through the loop, just gathering all the rows/columns into a variable before the loop begins, then sort this structure, then reassemble the table from the sorted structure.

Comment: You should always try to abstract data away from rendering. Store your table data as an array of objects and use the array sort function to sort that array however you like. Then create a document fragment and loop through the array adding objects as table rows and finally append the fragment to your table.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK `getElementsByTagName` would not work if there are nested tables. I feel `getElementsByTagName` is completely obsolete given that `querySelectorAll` supports `:scope` in modern browsers. `querySelectorAll` may even be faster than `getElementsByTagName` in complex documents if the selector prevents the browser from performing a full DOM tree traversal to every leaf node (e.g. using the child selector with `:scope`).

Comment: Guys, check out my function. It's so small and pretty, written in pure JS. It's blazing fast 156 ms - 190 ms.

Answer (score 11):

It helps to avoid implementing sorting algorithms in browser JavaScript because JavaScript's built-in [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method will be much faster even if you end-up implementing the same sort algorithm (IIRC most JS engines will probably use [QuickSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) anyway).

Here's how I'd do it:

- Get all of the `<tr>` elements in a JavaScript `Array`.

  - You need to use `querySelectorAll` in conjunction with `Array.from` because `querySelectorAll` **does not return an array**, it actually returns a `NodeListOf<T>` - but you can pass this into `Array.from` to convert it to an `Array`.
- Once you have the `Array`, you can use `Array.prototype.sort(comparison)` with a custom callback to extract the data from the `<td>` child of the two `<tr>` elements being compared, and then compare the data (using the `x - y` trick when comparing numeric values. For `string` values you'll want to use `String.prototype.localeCompare`, e.g. `return x.localeCompare( y )`.
- After the `Array` is sorted (which should not take more than a few milliseconds for even a table with tens of thousands of rows, [as QuickSort is really quick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)!) re-add each `<tr>` using `appendChild` of the parent `<tbody>`.

My implementation in TypeScript is below, along with a working sample with valid JavaScript in the script-runner located underneath:

```
// This code has TypeScript type annotations, but can be used directly as pure JavaScript by just removing the type annotations first.

function sortTableRowsByColumn( table: HTMLTableElement, columnIndex: number, ascending: boolean ): void {

    const rows = Array.from( table.querySelectorAll( ':scope > tbody > tr' ) );

    rows.sort( ( x: HTMLtableRowElement, y: HTMLtableRowElement ) => {
        const xValue: string = x.cells[columnIndex].textContent;
        const yValue: string = y.cells[columnIndex].textContent;

        // Assuming values are numeric (use parseInt or parseFloat):
        const xNum = parseFloat( xValue );
        const yNum = parseFloat( yValue );

        return ascending ? ( xNum - yNum ) : ( yNum - xNum ); // <-- Neat comparison trick.
    } );

    // There is no need to remove the rows prior to adding them in-order because `.appendChild` will relocate existing nodes.
    for( let row of rows ) {
        table.tBodies[0].appendChild( row );
    }
}

function onColumnHeaderClicked( ev: Event ): void {

    const th = ev.currentTarget as HTMLTableCellElement;
    const table = th.closest( 'table' );
    const thIndex: number = Array.from( th.parentElement.children ).indexOf( th );

    const ascending = ( th.dataset as any ).sort != 'asc';

    sortTableRowsByColumn( table, thIndex, ascending );

    const allTh = table.querySelectorAll( ':scope > thead > tr > th' );
    for( let th2 of allTh ) {
        delete th2.dataset['sort'];
    }

    th.dataset['sort'] = ascending ? 'asc' : 'desc';
}
```

My `sortTableRowsByColumn` function assumes the following:

- Your `<table>` element uses `<thead>` and has a single `<tbody>`
- You're using a modern browser that supports `=>`, `Array.from`, `for( x of y )`, `:scope`, `.closest()`, and `.remove()` (i.e. not Internet Explorer 11).
- Your data exists as the `#text` (`.textContent`) of the `<td>` elements.
- There are no `colspan` or `rowspan` cells in the table.

Here's a runnable sample. Simply click the column headers to sort in ascending or descending order:

```js
function sortTableRowsByColumn( table, columnIndex, ascending ) {

    const rows = Array.from( table.querySelectorAll( ':scope > tbody > tr' ) );
    
    rows.sort( ( x, y ) => {
    
        const xValue = x.cells[columnIndex].textContent;
        const yValue = y.cells[columnIndex].textContent;
        
        const xNum = parseFloat( xValue );
        const yNum = parseFloat( yValue );

        return ascending ? ( xNum - yNum ) : ( yNum - xNum );
    } );

    for( let row of rows ) {
        table.tBodies[0].appendChild( row );
    }
}

function onColumnHeaderClicked( ev ) {
    
    const th = ev.currentTarget;
    const table = th.closest( 'table' );
    const thIndex = Array.from( th.parentElement.children ).indexOf( th );

    const ascending = !( 'sort' in th.dataset ) || th.dataset.sort != 'asc';
    
    const start = performance.now();

    sortTableRowsByColumn( table, thIndex, ascending );

    const end = performance.now();
    console.log( "Sorted table rows in %d ms.",  end - start );

    const allTh = table.querySelectorAll( ':scope > thead > tr > th' );
    for( let th2 of allTh ) {
        delete th2.dataset['sort'];
    }
 
    th.dataset['sort'] = ascending ? 'asc' : 'desc';
}

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
    const table = document.querySelector( 'table' );
    const tb = table.tBodies[0];

    const start = performance.now();

    for( let i = 0; i < 9000; i++ ) {
        
        let row = table.insertRow( -1 );
        row.insertCell( -1 ).textContent = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 1000 );
        row.insertCell( -1 ).textContent = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 1000 );
        row.insertCell( -1 ).textContent = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 1000 );
    }

    const end = performance.now();
    console.log( "IT'S OVER 9000 ROWS added in %d ms.", end - start );
    
} );
```

```css
html { font-family: sans-serif; }

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
    table > thead > tr > th {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    table > thead > tr > th[data-sort=asc] {
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
    }
    table > thead > tr > th[data-sort=desc] {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
    table th,
    table td {
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
        padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th onclick="onColumnHeaderClicked(event)">Foo</th>
            <th onclick="onColumnHeaderClicked(event)">Bar</th>
            <th onclick="onColumnHeaderClicked(event)">Baz</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 9,000 additional rows will be added by the DOMContentLoaded event-handler when this snippet is executed. -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### A word on performance:

According to Chrome 78's Developer Tools' Performance analyzer, on my computer, the `performance.now()` calls indicate the rows were sorted in about 300ms, however the "Recalculate style" and "Layout" operations which happens *after* the JavaScript has stopped running took 240ms and 450ms respectively (690ms total relayout time, plus the 300ms sort time means it took a full second (1,000ms) from click-to-sorted).

When I changed the script such that the `<tr>` elements are added to an intermediate `DocumentFragment` instead of the `<tbody>` (so that each `.appendChild` call is *guaranteed* to not cause a reflow/layout, instead of just assuming that `.appendChild` won't trigger a reflow) and re-ran the performance test my result timing figures were more-or-less identical (they were actually slightly *higher* by about 120ms total after 5 repeats, for an average time of (1,120ms) - but I'll put that down to the browser JIT playing-up.

Here's the changed code inside `sortTableRowsByColumn`:

```
    function sortTableRowsByColumn( table, columnIndex, ascending ) {

        const rows = Array.from( table.querySelectorAll( ':scope > tbody > tr' ) );

        rows.sort( ( x, y ) => {

            const xValue = x.cells[columnIndex].textContent;
            const yValue = y.cells[columnIndex].textContent;

            const xNum = parseFloat( xValue );
            const yNum = parseFloat( yValue );

            return ascending ? ( xNum - yNum ) : ( yNum - xNum );
        } );

        const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
        for( let row of rows ) {
            fragment.appendChild( row );
        }

        table.tBodies[0].appendChild( fragment );
    }
```

I reckon the performance is relatively slow because of the Automatic Table Layout algorithm. I'll bet if I change my CSS to use `table-layout: fixed;` the layout times will shrink. (Update: I tested it with `table-layout: fixed;` and surprisingly that didn't improve performance at all - I can't seem to get better times than 1,000ms - oh well).

Comment: There's no need for `.remove()`. Just append them.

Comment: @Andreas ah, good catch! I forgot that `.appendChild` will move an element.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your answer. It does help me a lot. Now, do I have to include `onclick` for all columns? For example, the third column is not being sorted. So I don't have to include `onclick` for that column.. right?

Comment: @LeninMishra There are many ways to add event-handlers, `onclick` is just the simplest. You can also use `.addEventListener('click', onColumnHeaderClicked )` inside a script on the element objects you want to use too.

Comment: Have you tested this implementation with a table of 9K+ rows (as the OP mentioned). I was expecting to see _off-the-dom_ processing in a document fragment; that should speed up things quite a lot IMHO.

Comment: @customcommander Dai is using _"off-the-dom processing"_. He's sorting references and only changes the DOM after sorting the rows (but a `DocumentFragement` would still be slightly faster, because all rows would be added at once instead of one row at a time)

Comment: @Andreas I'm not convinced using `DocumentFragment` would be noticably faster at all in this case because browsers are not required to perform re-layout calculations or re-render the page after each-and-every DOM manipulation operation (e.g. `appendChild`) - instead they're free to coalesce them until needed - and the effect would not be noticable at all provided my function completes in under 1 frame's time anyway (e.g. 16.6ms at 60Hz).

Comment: @Dai the only way to know for sure would be to test your implementation with 9K rows and if that's "slow" try with a document fragment. Good to see you're somehow doing things off the DOM though.

Comment: @customcommander What do you mean by "off the DOM", exactly? That's not a term I'm familiar with - and I'm a software engineer who worked on Internet Explorer and Chakra when I was at Microsoft (and it's nonsensical anyway, because the script I wrote interacts directly with the DOM) - are you thinking of various DOM-esque libraries for server-side Node.js programs?

Comment: @Dai Let's say you have a long running for loop in which you keep appending new nodes to the DOM. This is most likely to be slower than creating a "container" (i.e. a document fragment) that is not connected to the DOM, add your new nodes to that container and then "drop" that container into the DOM. That way the browser doesn't recompute the layout all the time but just once. I used to do that back in the days. It may well be possible that these optimisation techniques are obsolete. Having said all that, I still think you should test your implementation with 9k rows though.

Comment: @customcommander As I mentioned in my earlier comment reply: browsers are not required to recompute the document layout after each DOM operation - all modern browsers today will coalesce layout and rendering operations between JavaScript script runs (unless the script performs an operation which requires an immediate relayout, such as using `getComputedStyle` or `getBoundingClientRect`). Because my script does not make use of any layout operations there shouldn't be any performance penalty - but you are completely correct about how I cannot be certain without first profiling my code! :D

Comment: @customcommander I added `performance.now()` calls to measure and it sorts through 9000 rows in about 300ms on my desktop (Chrome 78 x64 on Core i7 6850K). I'll try your suggestion to use `DocumentFragment` now.

Comment: @customcommander I've finished trying it with both `DocumentFragment` as you suggested and compared that to my direct `.appendChild` code and performance figures are essentially identical for both (actually slightly slower with `DocumentFragment`, sorry!) - that said, I think this is a bad test because of `table-layout: auto;` which will be slow for 9,000 table-cells regardless (the slow-down happens after the script has finished executing and happens inside the browser's reflow/relayout stage, and it's coalesced in both cases, so I don't think the script can do anything about it).

Comment: @customcommander I finished my testing with `table-layout: fixed;` and to my surprise and disappointment that didn't improve performance at all. Let me know in a comment-reply if you have any luck improving perf.

Comment: ``rows`` **is** an Array (with your sort order); the TRs _inside_ still point to the original TRs. So there is no need for a DocumentFragment **or** to loop over them ``table.tBodies[0].append(...rows)`` is enough

Comment: I have an issue with this script which I can't pinpoint. My table is mixed data, some columns numbers, some dates, some text. But even in case of numbers only columns, it makes a weird sort. I assume it's because of blank cells, so if cells go "10,3,5,blank,blank,10,3,5" once sorted it will do "3,5,10,blank,blank,3,5,10" instead "3,3,5,5,10,10" with blanks either on top or bottom. Same with desc. I'll play a bit more with it as it's way faster than any others I tried, but if anyone sees the reason, pls let me know. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, running `const xNum = xValue; const yNum = yValue;` (without ParseFloat) works for integers mixed with blank cells. So I may be on right track, probably the issue is with number only scheme, need to keep working on it to support text and dates

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function sort_table(tbody, index, sort = (a, b) => {
            if(a < b) return -1; if(a > b) return 1; return 0;}) 
        {
            var list = []
            for (var i = 0; i < tbody.children.length; i++)
                list.push([tbody.children[i].children[index].innerText, tbody.children[i]]);
            list.sort((a, b) => sort(a[0], b[0]));
            var newtbody = document.createElement('tbody');
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                newtbody.appendChild(list[i][1]);
            tbody.parentNode.replaceChild(newtbody, tbody);
            return newtbody;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Unsorted</h2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Nationality</th>
                <th>Born</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Henry</td><td>Cavill</td>
                <td>British</td><td>5 May 1983</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Gal</td><td>Gadot</td>
                <td>Israeli</td><td>30 April 1985</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Olga</td><td>Kurylenko</td>
                <td>Ukrainian</td><td>14 November 1979</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Vincent</td><td>Cassel</td>
                <td>French</td><td>23 November 1966</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
        var named = table.cloneNode(true);
        var dated = table.cloneNode(true);
        document.body.innerHTML += "<h2>Sorted by name</h2>";
        document.body.appendChild(named);

        sort_table(named.children[1], 0); //by name

        document.body.innerHTML += "<h2>Sorted by date</h2>";
        document.body.appendChild(dated);

        sort_table(dated.children[1], 3, (a, b) => { //by date
            if (new Date(a) < new Date(b)) return -1;
            if (new Date(a) > new Date(b)) return 1;
            return 0;
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**9000 rows (numbers) in 156 ms - 190 ms**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to sort a table on a column of addresses: 3 Autumn Lane, 1 Brandon Way, 10 Nature Lane, 100 Pristine Place ...  And wanted the sort on street names then house number.

To get that to work, I modified the sortTableRowsByContent function to split numbers from text.  Also, since some of my columns have blank values, I hide them when they sort:

```
function sortTableRowsByColumn( table, columnIndex, ascending ) {

const rows = Array.from( table.querySelectorAll( ':scope > tbody > tr' ) );

rows.sort( ( a, b ) => {

  const aValue = a.cells[columnIndex].textContent;
  const bValue = b.cells[columnIndex].textContent;
  const aNum = parseFloat( aValue );
  const bNum = parseFloat( bValue );

  const aNew = aValue.replace(/^\d{1,3} /, ""); 
  const bNew = bValue.replace(/^\d{1,3} /, "");

  if (ascending){
    return aNew.localeCompare(bNew) || parseInt(aNum) - parseInt(bNum);
  } else {
    return bNew.localeCompare(aNew) || parseInt(bNum) - parseInt(aNum);
  }

} );

for ( i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  if (rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[columnIndex].textContent == '') {
// this hides the blank rows
    rows[i].style.display = "none";
  } else {
// this restores blanks if a different column is sorted
    rows[i].style.display = "";
  }
};

for( let row of rows ) {
  table.tBodies[0].appendChild( row );
}
}
```